# set mixer increment/decrement when using hotkeys

Tags: linux, audio, debian, hotkeys, xfce4

Running XFce4 under Debian/GNU linux i'm facing the following problem with my audio mixer:

When I change the volume using the hotkeys, the volume is changed in too big steps.

So I tried attaching a script to the `XF86AudioLowerVolume` (and `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`) key (via *Settings->Keyboard->Application Shorcuts*) but
- the script never gets called
- i wonder whether this would actually disable the "other process" (that is changing the volume) if it did work

I also tried using `xbindkeys` as suggested on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10525) but it does the same (nothing).

Comment: Possibly the easiest solution would be to find out about that "other process" and learn how to configure it.